# How can I make it so that when I hover over an option in a dropped down a title is populated using Ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have many drop downs in a grid.  Is there a way that I can make jQuery do a call to Ajax to get the title when a user hovers over the text value in my select list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can make a call with jQuery to get the title when a user hovers over the text value, but you will probably not need to use ajax. Check out the .hover() function. This should be a good starting point.